# Backbone doesn't see Model changes on initialization. Is it normal?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, initialization, listener, backbone-events

On the Model initialization it sets some params. On the View initialization is the listener which must catch that event. But it doesn't. However it can do that on following events (like a button's click). So questions:

- Is it normal behavior?
- If yes then what is purpose of that
- If not, what is my error?

The place to play is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ddIZrkoI1n1CE6YrvMrC?p=preview

```
$(function(){
  var Mod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
          test:null
    },
    initialize: function(){
      this.set('test', 'hello');
      console.log(this.attributes);
    }
  });
  var Vw = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
      'click #btn-change' : function(){
        var mod_value = $('[name="data-input"]').val();
        console.log('mod_value: '+mod_value);
        this.model.set('test', mod_value);
      }
    },
    initialize: function(){
      console.dir({
        model: this.model,
        view: this
      }); 
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function(){
        console.log('%cModel changed', 'font-size:18px; color: navy');
        console.log({
          model_changed: this.model.changed,
                    keys: _.keys(this.model.changed),
                    attributes: this.model.attributes
        });
        $('#new-data').html('<h4>Model is changed</h4>'+this.model.get('test'));
      });
    }
  });
  var md = new Mod(), nv = new Vw({
    model: md,
    el:$('body')
  });
});
```

Comment: You create the model first, then listen to it, which the listen is registered after init complete, how would you expect view to listen to (and response to) something that is already complete?

Comment: See [altered plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Er87kuSJJ61cTWM0NWtF?p=preview), added a event listener before that `set`, and you can see Backbone DO see model change even if its initing, you just need to make sure listener registered before event happen.

Comment: Yes, but I need to hold the listener in my View, not in the Model to call appropriate View's method. How to solve this practical task it this case?

Comment: Why didn't call model with new attributes? `new Mod({test: 'hello'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that set event in model's initialization, as `model.changed` won't change until next `set`, and your handler doesn't depend on the params given by the event, you can either manually call the change event handler in your view's init, as [Altered Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/noTzzm3WJcyqtFPW1cRe?p=preview), or use `model.trigger('change', ...)` to trigger the change handler.

```
$(function(){
  var Vw = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
      'click #btn-change' : function(){
        var mod_value = $('[name="data-input"]').val();
        console.log('mod_value: '+mod_value);
        this.model.set('test', mod_value);
      }
    },
    initialize: function(){
      console.dir({
        model: this.model,
        view: this
      }); 
      // Pull the handler out as an attr of view's
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.onModelChanged);

      // Manually call the handler to get the changes made by mode's 
      // initialization.
      this.onModelChanged();
    },
    onModelChanged: function(){
        console.log('%cModel changed', 'font-size:18px; color: navy');
        console.log({
          model_changed: this.model.changed,
                    keys: _.keys(this.model.changed),
                    attributes: this.model.attributes
        });
        $('#new-data').html('<h4>Model is changed</h4>'+this.model.get('test'));
    }
  });
  var Mod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
      test:null
    },
    initialize: function(){
      this.set('test', 'hello');
      console.log(this.attributes);
    }
  });

  var md = new Mod(), nv = new Vw({
    model: md,
    el:$('body')
  });
});
```

Comment: Aha. Now I see. Just what I want. Thank you!